# Is this a bug in DotNet 4 WPF Spell Checking?

Tags: c#, wpf, spell-checking

I have:

1. Created a Windows forms project.
2. Created a UserControl to hold a WPF TextBox.
3. Added a CustomDictionary to the TextBox's SpellCheck.
4. Added the UserControl to my Windows Form.

XAML is used to add the WPF textbox to the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestElementHost.SpellBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="248" d:DesignWidth="250">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="txtWPF" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is the form code (buttons added in the VS designer file):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestElementHost
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost elementHost1;
        private SpellBox spellBox1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.elementHost1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost();
            this.spellBox1 = new TestElementHost.SpellBox();
            this.elementHost1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(27, 12);
            this.elementHost1.Name = "elementHost1";
            this.elementHost1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(269, 296);
            this.elementHost1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.elementHost1.Text = "elementHost1";
            this.elementHost1.Child = this.spellBox1;
            this.Controls.Add(this.elementHost1);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            spellBox1.txtWPF.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
            spellBox1.txtWPF.SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries.Add(new Uri(Application.StartupPath + @"\MyDictionary.lex"));
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            spellBox1.txtWPF.Text = "my bbad word."; // bbad is in the CustomDictionary
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            spellBox1.txtWPF.IsEnabled = false;
            spellBox1.txtWPF.IsEnabled = true;
           // spellBox1.txtWPF.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = false;
           // spellBox1.txtWPF.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This works quite happily and words in the CustomDictionary are ignored, until I try changing the IsEnabled, IsReadOnly or the Visibility property. For example, set IsReadOnly to true then straight back to false again and suddenly words that are in the customdictionary are redlined.

The way I am getting round this is to set SpellCheck.IsEnabled to false then back to true on consecutive lines when I need to allow users to edit text in the control. This seems to bring the customdictionary back into play.

Has anyone else had this problem? Is this a bug or have I missed something?

Comment: Are you using XAML or code only to add the WPF textbox to the UserControl?

Comment: TextBox is added to the UserControl using XAML

Comment: Hm, ok, less chance of initialisation errors then :) Is SpellCheck set in the XAML a'la `<TextBox x:Name="txtBox" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" ...` or set later in code?

Comment: Set later in the code... I've added the XAML to my original post.

Comment: I've also added the Windows form code to my original post now.

Comment: Can't find any documentation that would indicate that it's an expected behavior, and I can't really see a problem in your code either. I'm leaning towards bug (or at least unintended behavior), but that's just my opinion. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, good to know I'm not going mad. I've spent quite a bit of time writing WinForms apps, but WPF/XAML is new to me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a "feature" (thanks for verifying this Joachim):

If you are using the custom dictionary, then change the visbility, enabled or read only attributes of the WPF textbox or the user control, the spell checker ignores the custom dictionary.

To get round this, disable then re-enable spell checking.

This applies to dot net runtime v4.0.30319

Comment: Maybe you should post this at [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Comment: Good idea, just done that now. I wouldn't have known where to post without your link. Thanks.