# Why is there no IsReadOnlyChanged event on TextBox controls?

Tags: wpf, textbox, event-handling, spell-checking, readonly

I was adding some workaround code to fix the bug outlined in  [Is this a bug in DotNet 4 WPF Spell Checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001118/is-this-a-bug-in-dotnet-4-wpf-spell-checking), (When a WPF TextBox changes `Enabled,` `Visible` or `ReadOnly` states, any SpellCheck custom dictionaries get dropped off until you disable and re-enable SpellCheck) and the simplest fix seemed to be to handle the `IsVisibleChanged`, `IsEnabledChanged`, and `IsReadOnlyChanged` events.

Simple, right?  Except there **is** no `IsReadOnlyChanged` event.  Anybody know why and what the best way to trap a change to `IsReadOnly` in a WPF TextBox would be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always follow dependency property change with [DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.addvaluechanged.aspx)

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBoxBase.IsReadOnlyProperty)
                            .AddValueChanged(ctrl, OnReadOnlyChanged)
```

Comment: +1, but adding a sample for the concrete problem of the OP would greatly enhance your answer.

Comment: Cool.  I figured there had to be SOME way of handling this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class and handle OnPropertyChanged event. Sth like this:

```
public class MyTextBox: TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox() { }
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        if (e.Property.ToString() == "IsReadOnly")
        {
            // here you are sure that ContentPropertyhas changed
        }
    }
}
```